# Run Node commands for _www user

Tags: macos, mac, apache

I've installed NodeJS for all users on my Mac and when I do a `whoami` in the terminal it says 'cameron' and I can access node, npm, and grunt globally.

However when I try and run these from PHP e.g. `exec('npm install');` I can't run them because they don't exist! Doing a whoami in the PHP reveals that I'm running the website as `_www` which isn't an actual user on the Mac...

So basically how can I install Node for _www? So I can run these commands from PHP.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/9926627/2654989

Answer (score 1):

This fixes it (after changing apache to run as the user who has node or by giving access to _www).

```
putenv('PATH=' . getenv('PATH') . ':/usr/local/bin');
```